# Pydevd's effect on python's multiprocessing & threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, multiprocessing, pydev

What is the effect of `pydevd.py`'s -- pydev's debugger used by Eclipsed and Pycahrm -- effect on python's `multiprocessing` & `threading`?

When I start my python server -- which uses both `multiprocessing` & `threading` -- without debugging, it crashes on startup with no helpful traceback. However, when I run with Pycharm's debugger, the process starts up and functions properly.

So what would be causing this difference in performance? Could it be serialization of `Process()` or imposing of some orders on `Thread()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may be that you have some racing condition and just by having the debugger running things run in a different order (it does some monkey-patching to auto-attach to subprocesses and it does many things to reset its state in the new process).

Note that using `threading` and `multiprocessing` at the same time can be very tricky if you're starting your sub-processes with a `fork` on Linux (to resume, deadlocks are expected on corner cases if you do that) -- if you're on Python 2 there's no workaround, but if you're on Python 3 you should be able to set the start method to `spawn`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method.

I realize there are use cases where the `fork` method may be preferred vs `spawn` (to avoid copying too much memory on some use-cases). If that's your use case you should not use threads to continue using `fork` or you should be **very** careful about that interaction and reset anything that a thread could touch in the new process and remove references to all the threads and restart them in the new process (the debugger is multi-threaded and does a lot of things to try to work around that, but I'm still aware that just by having threads on some corner cases it could crash -- seldomly -- just because you're forking with those threads running depending on system level locks).

Comment: Could you tell me in details how `fork` and `threading` can interfere with each other? And the difference between `fork` and `spawn` other than what is mentioned in the python multiprocessing documentation? Maybe I should start a new question, so let me know if you feel more comfortable answering a new question.

Comment: The difference from `fork` to `spawn` is that `fork` will use forking and `spawn` will spawn a separate process and share objects by pickling/unpickling... I can't really give a good explanation in a comment related to forks and threads, but there are many resources related to that in the web (just search online for "fork and threads" -- it doesn't affect only python).